# How to suppress Pyodide Warning in PyScript?

Tags: pyscript, pyodide

I have the following PyScript + HTML example and I get the following error:

```
/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodide/__init__.py:74: FutureWarning: pyodide.create_proxy has been moved to pyodide.ffi.create_proxy Accessing it through the pyodide module is deprecated. warn(
```

**How I can suppress/remove the warning?**

**Why I get this error even when I use:**

```
from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PyScript Pyodide Warning</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>PyScript - Pyodide Warnning</h1>
    <input id="inp-cheese" type="text" placeholder="Want cheese? y|n">
    <input id="inp-bacon" type="text" placeholder="Want bacon? y|n">
    <input id="inp-mashrooms" type="text" placeholder="Want mashrooms? y|n">
    <input id="inp-paper" type="text" placeholder="Want paper? y|n">
    <button id="btn2" class="button-14" role="button">Go</button>

<py-script> 
from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy
from js import document

def on_btn2_click(event):
    global cheese
    global bacon
    global mashrooms
    global paper
    input_cheese = Element("inp-cheese")
    input_bacon = Element("inp-bacon")
    input_mashrooms = Element("inp-mashrooms")
    input_paper = Element("inp-paper")
    cheese = input_cheese.value
    bacon = input_bacon.value
    mashrooms = input_mashrooms.value
    paper = input_paper.value

button2 = document.querySelector("#btn2")
button2.addEventListener("click", create_proxy(on_btn2_click))
</py-script>

<py-repl id="my-repl-23nov22-0931" auto-generate="true"> 

if cheese == 'y':
    print("+ Cheese")
if bacon == 'y':
    print("+ Bacon")
if mashrooms == 'y':
    print("+ Mashrooms")
if paper == 'y':
    print("+ Paper")
print("_____")
</py-repl>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in [pyscript#867](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/867) and the fix should be included in the next release.

Otherwise, you could try to disable all warnings altogether,

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

but I'm not sure it would be called early enough in the `<py-script>` tag.

The other solution is to build the latest pyscript version, which includes the fix, and use that.